# Как не выгружать из памяти неактивные Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Часть из `MainActivity` для загрузки Fragment's:

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentNews(), "Новости");
    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentNonGroup(), "Общие вопросы");
    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentAlt(), "Альтернатива");
    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentLifeUbd(), "Жизнь с ВЗК");
    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentFood(), "Питание");
    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentSport(), "Спорт");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Код первого `Fragment` (остальные по аналогии):

```
public class FragmentNews extends Fragment {

    final ArrayList<NewsClass> newsList = new ArrayList<>();
    public Elements title;
    public Elements description;
    public Elements date;
    public Elements link;
    public Elements category;
    DrawerLayout drawer;
    int page = 1;
    String siteUrl = "***";

    private NewsAdapter adapter;
    private ListView lv;
    private FloatingActionButton fab;
    View v;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, container, false);
        fab = v.findViewById(R.id.fab1);


        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        lv = v.findViewById(R.id.news_list);
        adapter = new NewsAdapter(getActivity(), newsList);
        new NewThread().execute();

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Загрузка статей", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public class NewThread extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {

            try {

                Document doc;
                doc = Jsoup.connect(siteUrl + page).get();
                title = doc.select("div.td_module_5 > div > .entry-title");
                description = doc.select("div.td_module_5 > div > .td-excerpt");
                date = doc.select("div.td-module-meta-info > .td-post-date");
                link = doc.select("div.td_module_5 > div > .entry-title > a");
                category = doc.select("div.td_module_5 > div > .td-post-category");
                newsList.clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < title.size() && i < date.size() && i < link.size() && i < category.size(); i++) {
                    newsList.add(new NewsClass(title.get(i).text(), date.get(i).text(), link.get(i).attr("href"), category.get(i).text()));
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            fab.show();
            lv = v.findViewById(R.id.news_list);
            lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    fab.hide();
                    lv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Загрузка статей", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    newsList.clear();
                    page = page + 1;
                    new NewThread().execute();
                }
            });

            if (newsList.size() == 0) {
                fab.hide();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Других статей в этой категории нет", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                newsList.clear();
                page = page - 1;
                new NewThread().execute();
            }

            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                    NewsClass tempWord = (NewsClass) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    String contentTitle = tempWord.getmTitle();
                    String contentDate = tempWord.getmDate();
                    String contentUrl = tempWord.getmUrl();
                    String contentCategory = tempWord.getmCategory();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NewsContent.class);
                    intent.putExtra("TITLE_KEY", contentTitle);
                    intent.putExtra("DATE_KEY", contentDate);
                    intent.putExtra("URL_KEY", contentUrl);
                    intent.putExtra("CATEGORY_KEY", contentCategory);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
}}
```

При запуске приложения запускаются вкладки с фрагментами (для навигации перелистыванием влево-вправо) через `TabLayout`. Все данные во фрагментах грузятся с Интернета через `Jsoup`. Так вот в чем проблема - **всегда загружаются данные с двух соседних фрагментов**. При переходе на третий фрагмент данные с первого выгружаются из памяти, и при возврате на первый фрагмент они заново загружаются из сети.

Как сделать так, чтобы загруженные данные в ранее просмотренных фрагментах не выгружались из памяти, а были доступны при повторном просмотре этого фрагмента?

Может через сохранение\восстановление с базы данных в методах `onPause` и `onResume`?

Comment: Данные скорее не "выгружаются", а просто Вы не используете уже загруженные. Нужно переделать фрагменты так чтобы данные не загружались, если они уже есть. Сейчас у Вас нет никакого условия - в `onViewCreated` всегда запускается `NewThread`. Но - с другой стороны - что если на странице что-то изменилось между листанием фрагментов - отменив новую загрузку мы этого не увидим.

Comment: не подскажете, каким образом проверить данные на предмет их наличия? Условие напишу.

Comment: Допустим проверить `if (newsList.size() == 0)` - значит данные отсутствуют. Прочтите первый коммент - я его дописал. То есть тогда мы не увидим изменений сайта, пока у нас существуют уже загруженные данные.

Comment: if (newsList.size() == 0) {
            new NewThread().execute();    Не работает как нужно. То есть, при запуске приложения данные грузятся, все ок. При переходе на третий фрагмент и далее на первый - в первом пусто и ничего не грузится, что очевидно. Предполагаю, что загруженные данные все-таки пропадают...

Comment: Для обновления данных я напишу отдельный код, например по таймингу.

Comment: Отладка показывает, что newsList все-таки наполнен. Вопрос - как отобразить его после проверке условия?

Comment: Полагаю нужно в `else` продублировать часть (или весь) код из `onPostExecute`

Comment: Отлично, помогла строка в else lv.setAdapter(adapter); Напишите ответ, я помечу как решение :)

Comment: Вы можете сами опубликовать ответ на свой вопрос. Я могу только догадываться как выглядит код, которым Вы решили проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо было условие при запуске фрагмента. В итоге - при запуске проверка массива `newsList` на наличие в нем элементов. Если элементы есть - просто присваиваем `listview` ранее созданный `adapter`:

```
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

И за ним уже весь нужный нам для работы с этим listview код.

Если `newsList` = 0, то запускаем загрузку через `Jsoup`.

Готовый код первого Fragment:

```
public class FragmentNews extends Fragment {

final ArrayList<NewsClass> newsList = new ArrayList<>();
public Elements title;
public Elements description;
public Elements date;
public Elements link;
public Elements category;
DrawerLayout drawer;
int page = 1;
String siteUrl = "***";

private NewsAdapter adapter;
private ListView lv;
private FloatingActionButton fab;
View v;

@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, container, false);
    fab = v.findViewById(R.id.more);
    lv = v.findViewById(R.id.news_list);
    adapter = new NewsAdapter(getActivity(), newsList);
    if (newsList.size() == 0) {
        new NewThread().execute();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Загрузка статей", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        fab.show();
        lv = v.findViewById(R.id.news_list);
        lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                fab.hide();
                lv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Загрузка статей", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                newsList.clear();
                page = page + 1;
                new NewThread().execute();
            }
        });

        if (newsList.size() == 0) {
            fab.hide();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Других статей в этой категории нет", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            newsList.clear();
            page = page - 1;
            new NewThread().execute();
        }

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                NewsClass tempWord = (NewsClass) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                String contentTitle = tempWord.getmTitle();
                String contentDate = tempWord.getmDate();
                String contentUrl = tempWord.getmUrl();
                String contentCategory = tempWord.getmCategory();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NewsContent.class);
                intent.putExtra("TITLE_KEY", contentTitle);
                intent.putExtra("DATE_KEY", contentDate);
                intent.putExtra("URL_KEY", contentUrl);
                intent.putExtra("CATEGORY_KEY", contentCategory);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
    return v;
}

public class NewThread extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {

        try {

            Document doc;
            doc = Jsoup.connect(siteUrl + page).get();
            title = doc.select("div.td_module_5 > div > .entry-title");
            description = doc.select("div.td_module_5 > div > .td-excerpt");
            date = doc.select("div.td-module-meta-info > .td-post-date");
            link = doc.select("div.td_module_5 > div > .entry-title > a");
            category = doc.select("div.td_module_5 > div > .td-post-category");
            newsList.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < title.size() && i < date.size() && i < link.size() && i < category.size(); i++) {
                newsList.add(new NewsClass(title.get(i).text(), date.get(i).text(), link.get(i).attr("href"), category.get(i).text()));
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        fab.show();
        lv = v.findViewById(R.id.news_list);
        lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                fab.hide();
                lv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Загрузка статей", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                newsList.clear();
                page = page + 1;
                new NewThread().execute();
            }
        });

        if (newsList.size() == 0) {
            fab.hide();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Других статей в этой категории нет", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            newsList.clear();
            page = page - 1;
            new NewThread().execute();
        }

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                NewsClass tempWord = (NewsClass) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                String contentTitle = tempWord.getmTitle();
                String contentDate = tempWord.getmDate();
                String contentUrl = tempWord.getmUrl();
                String contentCategory = tempWord.getmCategory();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NewsContent.class);
                intent.putExtra("TITLE_KEY", contentTitle);
                intent.putExtra("DATE_KEY", contentDate);
                intent.putExtra("URL_KEY", contentUrl);
                intent.putExtra("CATEGORY_KEY", contentCategory);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}}
```

Спасибо @woesss за наводку.